# How to execute a XMLHttpRequest using onchange event of the select

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a web page and this web page I can't use php or another dynamic programming language and in this web page I want to get the result of a response from a REST API. I manage do this when the page is opened through this code:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.open( "GET", "https://..../select", true); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = processInitialRequest;

function processInitialRequest(e) {

    if ((xmlHttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlHttp.status == 200)){

        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        var i = 0;

        var select = document.getElementById("select_manufacturers");
        var content = select.innerHTML;

        for (i = 0; i< jsonObj.manufacturers.length; i++){

            //var opt = document.createElement("option");

            var arObj = jsonObj.manufacturers[i];

            var enable = arObj['enabled'];

            if(enable)
                select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(arObj['manufacturer'],arObj['id']);

        }   



    }

}
```

I have some `select` components in my webpage:

```
<select id="select_manufacturers" onchange="processManufacturersChange()">
        </select>
<select id="select_devicetypes">
        </select>
```

And when I change the `select_manufacturers` I want to load the `select_devicetypes` but when I do this:

```
    function processManufacturersChange(){

        var select = document.getElementById("select_manufacturers");


        var valueManufacturer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var textManufacturer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

        xmlHttpDeviceTypes.open("https://...../select?manufacturerId=" + valueManufacturer,true);

//process stop here

        xmlHttpDeviceTypes.send();

        xmlHttpDeviceTypes.onreadystatechange = processDeviceTypesRequest;

    }
```

the process has stopped at the `open` line. I already enabled CORS at my API but it does not work.

Console said:

> (index):149 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on
>   'XMLHttpRequest':
>   'https://.....amazonaws.com/v1/.../select?manufacturerId=10' is not a
>   valid HTTP method.
>       at processManufacturersChange (http://localhost/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/:149:21)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (http://localhost/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/:58:75)

Anyone can help me?

Thanks for understanding.

Comment: "the process has stopped at the open line" — That sounds unlikely. How are you determining that? What does the Console of your browser's developer tools say?

Comment: The process is not executed. I made two tests, 1) Put alert after the line and the alert is not shown. 2) console said it is a invalid URL.

Comment: So make it a valid URL. (We can't tell why it isn't valid, half of it is obscured with `https://..../select` and the other hand is obscured by being stored in a variable)

Comment: I've tried to use the URL of I want to open via Javascript in Chrome Browser and it works like a charm.

Comment: Now you've edited it to quote the error message … it doesn't say that it isn't a valid URL.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin you solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your answer is correct, i'll mark it as the correct answer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is not a valid HTTP method.

The **first** argument to `open` has to be the HTTP method, like `GET`, `PUT` or `POST`.

You are passing a URL as the first argument. The URL should be the **second** argument.